# incorrect syntax near '='

Tags: sql, syntax-error

The following SQL generates the error "incorrect syntax near '=' The issue seems to be with the select statement (alias TITER).  I've swapped out the TITER Select statement with other tables, and the SQL executes without the error. The error will not generate after I add the FULL OUTER JOIN; only after I type TITER.FLDDATE = TITER.FLDDATE in the SELECT statement in the CROSS APPLY section. My goal is to isolate for the reason for the error and correct the syntax if needed.

```
SELECT
    EMPLOYEE.FLDLNAME, 
    EMPLOYEE.FLDFNAME,
    EMPLOYEE.FLDREC_NUM,
    EMPLOYEE.FLDID2,
    TUBER_FLDDATE as "TUBER Date",
    TUBER_FLDCLASS as "TUBER Result",
    TITER.FLDDATE as "Titer Date"
FROM   EMPLOYEE 
CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT TUBER_FLDDATE = TUBER.FLDDATE,
            TUBER_FLDCLASS = TUBER.FLDCLASS,
            TITER.FLDDATE = TITER.FLDDATE
      FROM (SELECT rn = row_number() over(order by TUBER.FLDDATE),
              TUBER.FLDDATE, TUBER.FLDCLASS
            FROM TUBER 
            WHERE EMPLOYEE.FLDREC_NUM = TUBER.FLDEMPLOYEE
              and TUBER.FLDEMPLOYEE = '123') TUBER
        FULL OUTER JOIN 
            (Select rn = row_number() over(order by TITER.FLDDATE), 
                    TITER.FLDDATE 
             FROM TITER
             WHERE TITER.FLDTYPE = 'BAMT'
                AND EMPLOYEE.FLDREC_NUM = TITER.FLDEMPLOYEE
                and TITER.FLDEMPLOYEE = '123') TITER
           ON TITER.rn = TUBER.rn) tests
```

Comment: In the subquery, If `TITER.FLDEMPLOYEE = '123'`, what does `EMPLOYEE.FLDREC_NUM = TITER.FLDEMPLOYEE
` do? I think it may be superfluous.

Comment: EMPLOYEE.FLDREC_NUM = TITER.FLDEMPLOYEE  joins the main table (EMPLOYEE) to the subquery (TITER table). The TITER.FLDEMPLOYEE = '123' is just pulling a specific employee to make my query run quicker during development.

Comment: ahhh, yes, I've done that. Suggestion: that would be better as a nullable input parameter in a single Where clause predicate:  `and TITER.FLDEMPLOYEE = Coalesce(@employeeNbr,  EMPLOYEE.FLDREC_NUM)`

Answer (score 3):

I think you have an incidental period instead of an underscore:

`TITER.FLDDATE = TITER.FLDDATE` should be `TITER_FLDDATE = TITER.FLDDATE`

and then it parses successfully.

Comment: Good catch! I made that change it does run. I needed to add another full outer join in my cross apply section and I get the following error: "The multi-part identifier "TITER.FLDDATE" could not be bound". But because this is truly a different issue I will explore this error message and how to remedy.